# CMake Error OSVR Plugin - CMakeLists - The C/CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, osvr

Current settings are as follows.

Source Code = F:/OSVR Snapshot Build/Teensy OSVR Tracker

Build Path = F:/OSVR Snapshot Build/Teensy OSVR Tracker Plugin Build

CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = F:\OSVR Snapshot Build\OSVR-Core-Snapshot-v0.6-1935-ga2cba4b6-build281-vs12-64bit

When I hit Configure I get the Error popup "Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid"

In the Log window I get this:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
 No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/OSVR Snapshot Build/Teensy OSVR Tracker Plugin 
Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "F:/OSVR Snapshot Build/Teensy OSVR Tracker Plugin 
Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

All source files and error logs are at https://github.com/Hydr0Dr4gon/Teensy-OSVR-Tracker.
I put them there as there are a fair few files and it would get very messy here very quickly.

The OSVR-Core-Snapshot I am using is "OSVR-Core-Snapshot-v0.6-1935-ga2cba4b6-build281-vs12-64bit" and can be found here - http://access.osvr.com/binary/osvr-core

I am using Visual Studio Community 15 2017 and CMAKE 3.8.1

*EDIT*

Since launching CMake via VS Dev Console I now get this error.

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: 
CMakeDetermineTrackerCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: F:/OSVR Snapshot 
Build/TestBuild/CMakeFiles/3.8.1/CMakeTrackerCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_Tracker_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeTrackerInformation.cmake
```

Comment: Did you try running this from a Visual Studio 2017 command prompt?

Comment: I haven't tried. Never used CMake outside the GUI.

Comment: You can run cmake-gui from the command prompt. In that case it has the same environment as the command prompt (which in some cases helps it find packages ... ).

Comment: now I get a different error as described in the question edit